# Sending HTTP POST request does not pull the JSON data

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have an issue of not being able to send the HTTP POST request to Microsoft Graph within the Logic App. I have parsed JSON and trying to pull out the Id from the results, but sending the HTTP POST request shows that in the body that Id has not been provided.

[image]

[image]

This is the input to the HTTP POST request connector.

[image]

So, it does not take that Id from the JSON and add it to the body of the POST request.

I am using the v1.0 for the Graph.

[image]

This is what I am parsing out

```json
{
    "properties": {
        "body": {
            "properties": {
                "@@odata.context": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "businessPhones": {
                    "type": "array"
                },
                "displayName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "givenName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "jobTitle": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "mail": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "mobilePhone": {},
                "officeLocation": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "preferredLanguage": {},
                "surname": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "userPrincipalName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "headers": {
            "properties": {
                "Cache-Control": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Content-Type": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Date": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "OData-Version": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Strict-Transport-Security": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Transfer-Encoding": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Vary": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "client-request-id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "request-id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "x-ms-ags-diagnostic": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "x-ms-resource-unit": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "type": "object"
        },
        "statusCode": {
            "type": "integer"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

Comment: which graph API URL you are using in `HTTP 2`? are you making two HTTP calls here? If yes what is there in first call which you are passing in Parse_JSON's content. Please share your  Parse_JSON schema as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, it does not take that Id from the JSON and add it to the body of the POST request.

You have correctly designed the flow, only thing I have noticed while testing is that Id parameter will not get amended in request body if you would pass a blank value in the Payload like below.

[image]

[image]

Even I have the same design like you and when I am passing the value in Id, it is getting populated in request body.

[image]

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Alright. Issues with schema. Tested, now POST request get's the Id and gives the permissions to the AAD group. Thanks a lot for your help.